# BigQuery: How to load file from GCS to existing table using the transfer API?

Tags: python, google-bigquery, airflow

In airflow I want to load files from GCS to and existing BigQuery table. There is an operator that does that `GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator` which seems to create a new table every time. If I specify an existing table, it throws an error. How can I configure it so that I can load into an existing tables?

Comment: Can you share the code that you are currently running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem in general happens when you're not setting the  `write_disposition = "WRITE_APPEND"` property.
In the code below, for example, a CSV is being loaded from `GCS` to `BigQuery`.
If you remove the mentioned attribute, the table will be re-created each time the code runs.

```
run = GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator(
    bucket = "<bucket>",
    source_objects = ['gcs_to_bigquery/file.csv'],
    source_format = "CSV",
    field_delimiter = ",",
    skip_leading_rows = 1,
    destination_project_dataset_table = "<project>.<dataset>.gcs_composer_bq",
    task_id = 'xxxxxxxx',
    write_disposition = "WRITE_APPEND"
)
```

You can find all the existent attributes for this operator [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_api/airflow/contrib/operators/gcs_to_bq/index.html#module-contents)